# iterate through an arrayList of beans

Tags: jsp, loops, arraylist, javabeans, nested-loops

On my jsp I need to iterate through an ArrayList of javabeans and return a field within the bean. I initially started with a  loop and pulled my information in from session, but I am moving away from session to use the form bean. My ArrayList holds my beans.

This is my jsp code:

```
<logic:iterate name="ProjectCopyFormBean" property="copyToProject" id="bean">
  <logic:iterate name="bean" proprty="name" id="projectName">
    <option value="<bean:write name="projectName" />">
      <bean:write name="projectName" />
    </option>
  </logic:iterate>
</logic:iterate>
```

Without the inner logic:iterate, I am returned the bean location (com.*.*.*.ProjectBean@3c293c29)

I am willing to try something beyond logic:iterate as long as the solution doesn't use session, but the form bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I couldn't find anything by an internet search and did some trial and error

```
<logic:iterate name="ProjectCopyFormBean" property="copyToProject" id="bean">
  <bean:define id="projectBean" name="bean" />
  <option value="<bean:write name="projectBean" property="name"/>">
    <bean:write name="projectBean" property="name" />
  </option>
</logic:iterate>
```

Just like in the java code, you have to define your bean before you can use it.  After defining the bean, it works perfectly!